# php/mysql (appending html color codes to mysql table values)

Tags: php, mysql

This is php specific question. Is it possible to store html color codes in mysql table. So that when there is a php echo, it outputs the values in colors? For all my empty fields, I want to show the background color as red. Can I define a default function in mysql which will append a default color scheme to empty fields?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, pretty much the same way as for every other database value. (I would store HTML colour codes as `VARCHAR`s because of the possible variations). What part of the process is your question about?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly possible.

Comment: For all my empty fields, I want to show the background color as red

Comment: Now my last question is: why the MySQL? Have you heard about CSS?

Comment: hmmm, based on what i wanna do, css may not help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it it possible. You will save it as any other string.. so save "FF00FF" and than you will get this string from your db.
Edit: You don't have to store "#" I suppose - Depends on later use that you are planning.

Edit2: Is this about changing background color of table cell (during rendering) depending on its value? Your Q is unclear to me. But if I understand it correctly, then you can just make simple check like (pseudo):

```
if (value == null) color = "#FFFFFF";
echo color;
```

Depending on your rendering logic of course.

Comment: thats also a possibility. but i really want to fetch from database.

Comment: You should specify what exactly are you looking for, because we obviouusly don't get it now ;)

Comment: by default: i want to give all my empty mysql table fields one color. So if they're not empty, then no color. This means all empty fields in my db will have a specific color code. When that field is now filled, there should be no color.

Comment: But database is just a data storage somewhere on harddrive.. and you are talking about some tables and color codes. So its related to specific view of that database. And we need to know which one? Are you talking about coloring cells in phpMyAdmin or in some custom view in your application?

Comment: its about customed views. I want to research about using jquery for this. Thanks pal.